# Special AWK command for Final Record

Tags: awk

I am using the following script to count unique strings in a sorted set.

```
awk '{if (p==$1) print 0,p;else print 1,p} {p=$1}' 1.txt > 2.txt

Input
a
a
a
b
c
c
d
d
d

output
0 a
0 a
1 a
1 b
0 c
1 c
0 d
0 d
0 d
```

I am using a 1 to designate when a unique set ends and a new one begins, however awk does not add the 1 to the last set because there is no next line to compare it to.  Is there a way I can designate a special behavior when there is no next line?

Currently I am adding in the step following shell scripts to deal with this but I would like a way to do it within the awk script.

```
lines=`wc -l sort.txt| cut -d " " -f 1`
awk -v a=$lines '{if (p==$1) print 0,p;if (p!=$1||NR==a) print 1,p} {p=$1}' sort.txt > index.txt
```

Comment: Is not very clear what you want, because your input file does not return what the output part indicates. Can you cross check it?

Comment: His input matches his output as far as I can tell. He is prepending a 0 or 1 to each line.

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks for catching that. I was not printing my first line, due to the same problem which was preventing me from printing my last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this script to work.

```
awk 'BEGIN{p=$1}{if ($1==p) print 0,p;if (p!=$1&&p!="") print 1,p} {p=$1}END{print 1,p}' 1.txt


input 
a
a
a
b
c
c
d
d
d


output
0 a
0 a
1 a
1 b
0 c
1 c
0 d
0 d
1 d
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `END {...}` block to do something when awk has finished processing all input (or has been told to `exit`).

Comment: I have tried this but every way I do it, this only duplicates the final record (With the 1 value now at $1).  Any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: I see that you figured this out. Yeah, you just need to manually "close" your last seen field in the `END` block.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to change what you print:

```
awk '{if (p==$1) print 0,$1;else print 1,$1} {p=$1}' 1.txt
```

```
1 a
0 a
0 a
1 b
1 c
0 c
1 d
0 d
0 d
```

Comment: If we're playing golf: `awk '{$2=$1;$1=p!=$2;p=$2}1'`

Comment: can you think of a way to get the 1 to be at the end of the set rather than at the beginning?

Comment: Just set $2 to be the 0/1 value: `awk '{$2=p!=$1;p=$1}1'` or more readably `awk '{if (p == $1) {$2 = 0} else {$2 = 1}; p = $1; print}'` -- or if there are other fields, instead of `$2` use `$(NF+1)`

Answer (score 0):

This prints `1` at last letter.

```
awk 'NR>1 {print p==$1?0 FS p:1 FS p} {p=$1} END {print 1,$0}' file
0 a
0 a
1 a
1 b
0 c
1 c
0 d
0 d
1 d
```